# Why doesn't Import work with XOWA offline Wikipedia database?

Tags: import, interoperability, java, html, wikipedia

I'm having trouble with importing HTML from [XOWA](http://xowa.sourceforge.net/) offline wikipedia database. I set up a local server for datamining, but I can't access it with Mathematica. I can request a HTML page with `curl` or `wget`, but Mathematica's `Import[]` crashes the XOWA server with

```
failed to process request;
request=<<NULL>>
err_msg=[err 0] <gplx> invalid content_type: line=Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded request=type: GET url: /en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test    protocol: HTTP/1.1  host: localhost:8080    user_agent: Wolfram HTTPClient 10.2 accept: */* accept_encoding: <<NULL>>   dnt: false  x_requested_with: <<NULL>>  cookie: <<NULL>>    referer: <<NULL>>   content_length: 0   content_type: <<NULL>>  content_type_boundary: <<NULL>> connection: <<NULL>>    pragma: <<NULL>>    cache_control: <<NULL>>
[trace]:
  gplx.core.net.Http_request_parser.Parse_content_type(Unknown Source)
  gplx.core.net.Http_request_parser.Parse(Unknown Source)
  gplx.xowa.servers.http.Http_server_wkr_v2.Run(Unknown Source)
  gplx.xowa.servers.http.Http_server_wkr_v2.Invk(Unknown Source)
  gplx.core.threads.Thread_adp.run(Unknown Source)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using `ImportString[Import["!curl \"http://localhost:8080/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"<>link<>"\"","Text"],"XMLObject"]` at the moment but I'm interested in fixing the problem with direct importing. Unfortunately I don't understand the Java errors so I can't debug this myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an issue with XOWA. The HTTP Server was rewritten in v2.7.2 to handle POSTs and other features. However, it looks like it crashes on your request.

I'll look at fixing this for v2.8.2. I'll comment again here when I have a resolution, but feel free to contact me directly for more info.

Hope this helps!

[Edit: This was fixed for v2.8.2. XOWA now accepts GET requests with a Content-Type. See https://github.com/gnosygnu/xowa/releases ]

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I look forward to using the fixed server.

Comment: I have a fix ready for this. I created a ticket here with more info: https://github.com/gnosygnu/xowa/issues/17 . Basically, XOWA became more strict about the request headers in v2.7.2 and rejected GET requests with headers of Content-Type. `curl` and `get` probably work b/c they don't submit Content-Type headers, but Mathetmatica fails.

This has been relaxed for v2.8.2 which will be released on Monday. If you want a version before then, let me know what OS and bitness, and I'll make a temporary build for you.

Comment: Also, are you planning to mine all the <math> statements in English Wikipedia? If so, I can probably put together a sqlite database for you with these columns: page_namespace, page_name, math_source. This will take me 4 days to generate, but it will probably be faster than running it thru the HTTP server. I can also provide instructions as well if that's where you're headed.

Let me know if you have any questions. And thanks again for reporting the issue!

Comment: I am actually interested in creating article link connectivity graphs, inspired by [Wikipedia:Getting to Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy) but also for other common words besides "philosophy". I wrote a pretty robust parser that handles a couple of thousand articles, which I more or less thoroughly checked "by hand", without fail. The only issue is the speed, it can process only 100 - 200 articles per minute. Most of the time is spent requesting the article from the server, processing it to an `XMLObject` and then parsing it for the correct link.[cont.]

Comment: [cont.] So I would appreciate if there was a way to create a database containing article's title and its (namespace 0) links (titles, not IDs), however I would still somehow have to check for each link if it satisfies the rules - not italic, not in parentheses, etc. Let me know if it's possible. And also, in the meantime before you push the updated XOWA version, I guess I can just get around this issue if I specify an empty Content-type header?

Comment: I actually have a database that has `page_id`, `link_id` (ascending integer assigned to each link as they appear on page) `link_namespace` and `link_title`. There are 2 problems though. The database is large (33 GB uncompressed). Also, it tracks each link including those in the infobox and other header pieces (disambiguation). You won't be able to tell if something is in the introductory paragraph, which comes after these pieces, and I think is what you need. At any rate, if you want to take a whack at it, I can compress it and upload somewhere. I don't think it'll fit on my google drive...

Comment: I added a fix for v2.8.2. https://github.com/gnosygnu/xowa/releases . I can't test it with the Import feature, but it should work. If it doesn't, let me know the error and I'll investigate. Thanks.

Comment: It works, thanks again! I have accepted your answer but please edit it so that it contains the info from your last comment.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 4):

As @gnosygnu mentioned in the comments of his answer, the problem is with the `"Content-Type"` header. So as a temporary fix before XOWA is updated, this works:

```
ImportString[URLFetch["http://localhost:8080/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test",
"Content","Headers"->{"Content-Type"->""}],"XMLObject"]
```